# Proving a claim about extremas of continuous functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity, maxima-minima

I'm trying to prove the following claim:

> Let $f, g : [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions. Assume that $(x^*,y^*) \in (0,1)$ is the only point satisfying $$\begin{cases}f(x^*, y^*)=\max\limits_{x} f(x,y^*) \\ g(x^*, y^*)=\max\limits_{y} g(x^*,y)\end{cases}$$
>
> Define
> $$\begin{cases}\alpha := \max\limits_{x \in [0,1]}\,\, \min\limits_{y \in [0,1]} f(x,y) \\ 
> \beta := \max\limits_{y \in [0,1]}\,\,\, \min\limits_{x \in [0,1]} g(x,y)\end{cases}$$
>
> Prove that $\min\limits_{y \in [0,1]} f(x^*,y)=\alpha$ and $\min\limits_{x \in [0,1]} g(x,y^*)=\beta$.

My approach here was to define $k(x)=\min\limits_{y \in [0,1]} f(x,y)$ and $l(y)=\min\limits_{x \in [0,1]} g(x,y)$. $k$, $l$ are continuous, and satisfy $\alpha=\max\limits_x k, \beta=\max\limits_y l$. We want to show that $k(x^*)=\alpha, l(y^*)=\beta$.

I tried each equality by showing the two inequalities $\le, \ge$, and I tried to prove these by contradiction. It unfortunately didn't work.

I think that my problem was that I didn't manage to use the fact the game is over the unit square. Perhaps it may be helpful by defining an infinite sequence and showing convergence. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also by $\min$ or $\max$ , you mean $\mbox{argmin}$ or $\mbox{argmax}$ in some places, I think. That is, when you are saying that $x^* = \max_{x} f(x,y^*)$, what you actually mean is $f(x^*,y^*)$ is the maximum value of $f(x,y^*)$ as $x$ ranges over $[0,1]$. This is referred to as the "argument minimum/maximum".

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: The claim is incorrect. Counterexample: $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1-x-y&x+y\ge1\\2(x+y-1)&y\ge1/2,x+y\le1\\4(x+y-1)&x\ge1/2,x+y\le1\\8xy-2x-1&x\le1/2,y\le1/2\end{cases}$, $g(x,y)=-|x-y|$, $(x^*,y^*)=(1/2,1/2)$.